# Why my rdp access to Linux consumes way more bandwidth than a rdp connection to a Windows 10 machine?

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, remote-desktop, remote-access, rdp

I have a first VM running Ubuntu 18.04 as a guest, and a second VM running Win10 as a guest, both powered by virtualbox.

I have enabled on the 2 VMs the `VRDP` option to allow remote access.

I can connect fine via my PC rdp to both the VMs with the access to the linux VM being slightly slower than the Windows machine, but still very workable.

The issue is that the bandwidth consumption when connecting to the Linux machine is way higher than when connecting to the Windows VM. The below screenshot gives better view:

[Task manager screenshot showing network consumption difference between rdp to ubuntu vs rdp to windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0ICh.png)

Any suggestion on an Ubuntu configuration tip that can fix this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that `Remote Desktop Manager Free Edition` does also use `rdp`, but consumes the bandwidth more sparingly (around 50 meg per hour : previously it was more like 500 meg per hour) while connecting to Ubuntu guest on virualbox with `vrdp` activated.

Comment: But still not as good as rdp to windows guest.